# Symfony 2 + Doctrine, joining 3 tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have 3 entities: Game, Platform (like PC, XBOX, PS3 and so on) and Image.

Game can be released on many platforms, platform can be related to many games, and finally game can have many box covers (for example one for each platform).

I want to relate those 3 entities by join table.
I did some reading and found that i should create another entity to describe relations, and I did.

Now I have 4th entity GameCovers with fields: game_id, platform_id and image_id.
Everything seems to work - doctrine generated getters and setters. My question is how do I fetch data from DB?

In Game Enity now I have method:

```
/**
* Get game_covers
*
* @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
*/
public function getGameCovers()
{
   return $this->game_covers;
}
```

But how do i fetch box cover for just one platform for example: PC?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at custom entity repositories:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Inside each of methods you would then `createQuery`, e.g.:

```
# Fetch all the games that have PC release
public function getPcGames(){
    $q = $entityManager->createQuery("SELECT gc,p,g FROM GameCover gc JOIN gc.platform p JOIN gc.game g WHERE p.name = :platformName");
    $q->setParameter('platformName', 'PC');
    return $q->getResult();
}
```

This is, obviously, over simplified example but the key point is not to rely on getters but rather create your own queries....

Comment: Maybe that's because the code is poorly formatted, and incomplete.

Comment: Hmm, my guess would be that you are not really answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, `$em->getRepository('GameCover')->findOneBy(array('platform' => $platform, 'game' => $game))` where platform and game are the respective objects, or ids.

You can use a custom repository for GameCover to do this for you under a different method.

If you use getGameCovers you'll trigger the initialisation of the proxy holding all the game covers and doctrine will fetch all of them from the database. So if you don't want to do this, just fetch the specific one you want from the GameCover repository.

Comment: Thaks for an answer, but the problem is i have only one record of a game no matter for how many platforms it was released.
For example: "Dishonored" is one record in game table, but it was released for 3 platforms so there are 3 records in game_platform table.

Comment: I don't understand why that is a a problem... fetch the game you want, check if it's on the platform you want, then fetch the cover for that game.

Comment: Maybe i dont understand something. Symfony2 and Dictrine are still kinda new to me. I was using Symfony1 and Propel for long time.

Isnt $game from your example still same object since its just one and same record from game table?